# Couldn't understand why two programs did not return same results

Tags: python, list

Program 1:

```
lines = [['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 0],
    ['5.2', '2.5', '1.3', '0.1', 1]]
for line in lines:
    line = [float(i) for i in line]
    print(line)
print(lines)
```

Program 2

```
lines = [['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 0],
    ['5.2', '2.5', '1.3', '0.1', 1]]
for line in lines:
    for i in range(len(line)):
        line[i] = float(line[i])
    print(line)

print(lines)
```

Couldn't understand why each line had been modified but lines had not, can anyone explain why?

Comment: In program 1 `line` referring to the new variable after 1st line of for loop, whereas in Program 2 you are changing the original list.

Comment: A duplicate again

Answer (score 2):

In the Program 1, you are reassigning new value to `line` element. Hence it is not referring the same `lines` element, it has a new address after assignment is done using assignment operator(=).

**Output**:

```
[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 0.0]
[5.2, 2.5, 1.3, 0.1, 1.0]
[['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 0], ['5.2', '2.5', '1.3', '0.1', 1]]
```

**Observe** that you have passed `lines` elements as string and you are getting `lines` as it is. But `line` elements as float(which is not reflected in `lines`).

In the Program 2, you are accessing the element of `line` which is the element of `lines`. It is holding address of `lines` element.

**Output**:

```
[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 0.0]
[5.2, 2.5, 1.3, 0.1, 1.0]
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 0.0], [5.2, 2.5, 1.3, 0.1, 1.0]]
```

**Observe** that you have passed `lines` elements as string and now you are getting `lines` elements as float.

Comment: Is it an unique behavior for python? Never noticed this in other programming languages

Comment: Hi buddy, welcome to stackoverflow, To be very true, I am not that much aware of any other language, but it happens in python.
By the way if this answer satisfied your craving for knowledge kindly upvote my answer its keep me motivated.